# How to get fd of child.stdin?

Tags: node.js

How to get `fd` of `child.stdin` to do `fs.writeSync/readSync`? `'open'` never gets fired.

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const child = spawn('cat');
const cmd = 'foo\n';
let buff = new Buffer.from(cmd);
// child.stdin.fd is undefined
child.stdin.write(buff);

// never gets called
child.stdin.on('open', function (fd) {
  fs.writeSync(fd, buff, 0, buff.length, null, err => {
    if (err) throw 'Could not send command: ' + err;
    console.log('Command succesfully sent');
  });
});

child.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
  // echo
  process.stdout.write(chunk.toString());
});

child.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fd` of `child.stdin` can be accessed via `child.stdin._handle.fd`. Not sure if this is recommended but I tested it in both v0.12.10 and v10.16.0.